# MySQL - rank function inside where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I want to use rank function in my MySQL query. I used advice from [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

I want to select only one row with highest rank. My query looks like:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM tab1 t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
WHERE t.c5 = 'asd' AND t.c6 = 'qwe' AND rank = 1 
ORDER BY t.c8 DESC
```

And I receive following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'rank' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong? How I can fix my query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the `ALIAS` that was generate on the same level as the `WHERE` clause, you can wrap it with subquery. Eg,

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT c1, c2, c3, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
   FROM tab1 t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
   WHERE t.c5 = 'asd' AND t.c6 = 'qwe' 
   ORDER BY t.c8 DESC
) a
WHERE rank = 1
```

The SQL Order of Operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

The `ALIAS` is created on the `SELECT` clause so it is not yet accessible on the `WHERE` clause.